# MongoDB Aggregation $lookup $match

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

my Connection collection have ObjectId Array field named authors. I want to concat all first names and last names from author arrays.Right now I get name from all users in collection. Can't get $match aggregation to work. Thank you!

Connections Schema

```
const connectionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  authors: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true }],
  messages: [messageSchema]
});
```

Problem in code

```
   const connections = await Connection.aggregate([

    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        let: { users: "users" },
        pipeline: [
          { $match: { _id: { $in: ["_id", "$authors"] } } },
          {
            $project: {
              name: {
                $concat: ["$firstname", " ", "$lastname"]
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        as: "userName"
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `authors` field in `connection` schema. So instead use `authors` in `let` variable to get use in `users` pipeline **`{ "$in": ["$_id", "$$authors"] }`**.

```
const connections = await Connection.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "let": { "authors": "$authors" },
      "pipeline": [
        { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": ["$_id", "$$authors"] } } },
        {
          "$project": {
            "name": {
              "$concat": ["$firstname", " ", "$lastname"]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "userName"
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: thank you, that's it..I understand now but can you tell me just what mean $expr